# How much of previous economics (historically) is still relevant today?

Tags: history-economic-thought

How much of previous economics (historically) is still relevant today?

How is it determined?

Is e.g. 18th century economics still relevant today? Is it accurate/useful to cite Adam Smith for example?

It's clear that people still cite e.g. Smith or Marx, but one could question, whether such citing serves a "purposeful" description of contemporary reality or whether it's merely made plausible to "apply Marx today", because one can.

Comment: [This question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/a-timeline-on-the-the-key-achievements-of-economics-and-its-evolution?rq=1https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/a-timeline-on-the-the-key-achievements-of-economics-and-its-evolution?rq=1) is relevant, displaying a summarised history of the evolution of economics.